# Insert html text into .odt OpenOffice document with C#

Tags: c#, openoffice-writer, uno

Please, help anyone who worked with OpenOffice Writer document in C#. How can insert an HTML formated text into the document? The following code:

```
((unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument)xComponent).getText().getStart().
    setString("The <b>first line </b> in the newly created text document.\n\n");
```

inserts exactly `The <b>first line </b> in the newly created text document.`

I need to insert "The **first line** in the newly created text document"

Any solution?

Comment: did you found answer ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert formatted text - then you need to change the (paragraph/character) properties.

As you seen already OOo not react on HTML tags  ;-)

Comment: can you show some example or links where Description can be found

Comment: I'm not having this for C#.
My main source for learning StarBasic was Andrew Pitonyak (http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php)