# Insert HTML Text Into OpenOffice Document (.odt) Files

Tags: c#, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer, openoffice-api

I am Trying to Insert HTML Text Inside *Apache Open Office* `.odt` File

I try Statement with `Bold` as show Below but it is not Working.

Is There I am missing Something ?

```
XComponentContext oStrap = uno.util.Bootstrap.bootstrap();
        XMultiServiceFactory oServMan = (XMultiServiceFactory)oStrap.getServiceManager();

  XComponentLoader oDesk = (XComponentLoader)oServMan.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop");
    string url = @"private:factory/swriter";
PropertyValue[] propVals = new PropertyValue[0];

XComponent oDoc = oDesk.loadComponentFromURL(url, "_blank", 0, propVals);
string docText = "<b>This will</b> be my first paragraph.\n\r";
docText += "This will be my second paragraph.\n\r";
((XTextDocument)oDoc).getText().setString(docText);
string fileName = @"C:\test.odt";
fileName = "file:///" + fileName.Replace(@"\", "/");
((XStorable)oDoc).storeAsURL(fileName, propVals);
((XComponent)oDoc).dispose();
oDoc = null;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: is it giving some kind of error? or giving the text as an output but not in bold

Comment: @Codeek check Updated ...

Answer (score 0):

As answered already in [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384355/insert-html-text-into-odt-openoffice-document-with-c-sharp?rq=1) - you have to use character properties to get bold (or otherwise attributed) text

Comment: i Already build Long HTML for `Exporting MS Word ` I want to find solution or is there is any way i can inject HTML directly inside these `.odt` files